# Change button function on press?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I am working on a XCode 4.4 project and I am at a point where I need to conserve some space in my GUI. I have two buttons that each handle a method, one to power on a device and the other to power off the same device.

My question is how can I combine these two buttons into one so when the user presses the power on button it changes to the power off button and so on. I need to be able to change the icon on the button as well to display a change. I would think this is generally pretty simple to achieve. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all you need to do is when the button is pressed, update the button to reflect the current state. So you will change the image on the button and probably the text. Just look at the documentation of `NSButton` for what you can set.

So you might do something like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender {
    if (device.isTurnedOn) {
        [device turnOff];
        [self.button setTitle:@"Turn On"];
    } else {
        [device turnOn];
        [self.button setTitle:@"Turn Off"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the NSButton class for my project and I looked at its reference and it wasn't easily understandable.

Comment: Whoops sorry, my bad, will fix.

Comment: Sorry I just assumed iOS without looking. Have fixed. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single action like this.

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {

     NSButton *btn=(NSButton *)sender;

    [btn setTitle:([btn.title isEqualToString:@"On"] ? @"Off" : @"On")];

    if([btn.title isEqualToString:@"On"]){
        //Switch ON the device
    }else{
        //Switch OFF the device
    }
}
```